# Dynamically adding HTML to ASP.NET page with C#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I'm trying to create a simple store locator on an ASP.NET page. I have the user enter their zipcode, then C# creates a variable with it and appends it to the end of a url to search for that store on Google maps near them. I then need it to dynamically add an iframe tag with it's source as that url to the page.

Something like:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" placeholder="Zip code" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Find locations" onclick="Button1_Click" />
```

And:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var zipCode = TextBox1.Text;

    HtmlGenericControl iframe = new HtmlGenericControl();
    iframe.ID = "iframe";
    iframe.TagName = "iframe";
    iframe.Attributes["class"] = "container";
    iframe.Attributes["src"] = "https://www.google.com/maps/preview#!q=gnc+near%3A+" + zipCode;
    this.Add(iframe);

}
```

I believe it's correct until the last line, any thoughts?

Comment: You could add it the iframe control to a `Placeholder` control. This is also a one-liner with jQuery and wouldn't require a postback, if you have that option.

Comment: Why not just put it into a div and then display the div instead of trying to add the iframe to the page?

Comment: We do, how would it be done with jQuery?

Comment: Having never done this before, what's wrong with the iframe?  It's what Google recommends for embedding maps. https://support.google.com/maps/answer/72644?hl=en

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually add `runat="server"` to any standard HTML tag on the page in ASP.NET webforms.  Try this on your page:

```
<iframe id="MyIframe" runat="server"></iframe>
```

This will give you access to your iframe by name in code behind.  You'll then be able to manipulate things by writing statements like:

```
MyIframe.Visible = true;
```

and

```
MyIframe.Attributes.Add("src", "https://www.google.com/maps/preview#!q=gnc+near%3A+" + zipcode);
```

Comment: That looks like a great solution! I tried it but it's saying that my iframe is a field but it's being used as a type. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Oops, my bad, had an extra bracket.